# Is QNetworkReply::finished() signal called sequentially or simultaneously?

Tags: c++, qt, httprequest

It's a HTTP request sending method. When the goal website responses, httpFinished() will be called.

```
void HTTPClientBase:: HttpRequestGet()
{
    QNetworkRequest network_request;

    network_request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    network_request.setUrl(URL);

    reply = network_manager.get(network_request);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(httpFinished()));
}

void HTTPClientBase::httpFinished()
{
    // process the reply;
}
```

I can call HttpRequestGet() in a loop.

```
static HTTPClientBase myClient;
for(...)
{
  myClient.setUrl(...);
  myClient.HttpRequestGet();
}
```

Since the the request and response are async, so the loop can be done within an instant time. After several hundreds milliseconds, httpFinished() will be called successively.

I want to know httpFinished() will be called sequentially or simultaneously. In other words, if I need to concern simultaneous-programming problems, for example, writing the response datas into a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statements indicate that the httpFinished method will not be executed more than once at the same time:

- Slots are invoked when no synchronous task is executed.
- HTTPClientBase is a QObject that lives in a thread so the execution of any of its methods implies that you cannot execute another task.
- The task you do is not concurrence only an asynchronism.
- The asynchronism of Qt is valid from a design point of view but actually executes its tasks synchronously.
- In one thread only one task can be executed at a time and httpFinished is executed in the thread where HTTPClientBase lives.

Comment: Thanks! The conclusion is same with my guess. But the strange thing is: I sent 100 requests and httpFinished was called only 97 times. I wrote the replies into a file no matter the request was succeeded or failed. I had thought if the synchronous caused the problem.

Comment: @Zhang You could provide an MRE of your test to analyze where the problem is, maybe what you see is caused by an error in the part of your code that you don't show.